# What is the minimum passport validity for traveling to Turkey?

Tags: passports, turkey, malaysian-citizens

I'm Malaysian student in Jordan. I'm planning to travel to Kuala Lumpur via Turkish Airlines on the next month. Based on the flight details on Turkish Airlines webpage, I should transit in Istanbul (Ataturk International Airport) about 19 hours (from 06:06 am to next day 01:15 am.) Because of the transit period is very long, I plan to participate Touristanbul journey (http://www.istanbulinhours.com).

My problem is the validity of my wife's and one of my daughter's passport is less than 6 months now (expired on 8/9/2015).

My question is am I and my family eligible to participate in Touristanbul journey with passport validity less than 6 months?

Answer (score 3):

[Visa Information For Foreigners](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) says

> You are kindly advised to have a travel document/passport valid for at least 6 months as from the date of your arrival in Turkey.

On the other hand, http://www.redfern-travel.com/about/news/travel-news/792-turkey-change-to-passport-validity-requirements-as-of-01-january-2015 it seems new measures are in place since Jan 1, 2015. A lot of webpages indicate this to be the up-do-date regulation:

> All visitors travelling to Turkey from 01 January 2015 will be required to have 60 days validity on their passport from the expiry date of the visa.

Going back to the Ministry page, under Malaysia:

> Ordinary and official passport holders are exempted from visa for their travels up to 90 days.

so then you are looking at, presumedly, 90+60=150 days aka 5 months from the day of entry. Here's a [page](http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/details/BorderFormalities/) corroborating my suspicion on how to calculate when you don't need a visa:

> You will not be allowed to enter Turkey if your passport is not valid for at least two months beyond the end of your PERMITTED period of stay.

Next month is April enough, you need at least 5 months of validity which you don't have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about airport hotel, can I get it? My husband and my 2 child (infant and son) of course can get it, but how about me and one of my daughter? Do they have a consideration?

Comment: http://www.ataturkairport.com/en-EN/shoppingdinning/Pages/AirportHotel.aspx this claims to be air side so yes, this is an option.